# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null (I have not found a solution)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a `GridView1`

[image: This is my Page and the gridview is filled]

[image: This how it looks like in the bowser]

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

I have filled the `gridview1` in my c#

```
DataTable dt = GetTable(sSavePath, strFileType);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

This is my code for JavaScript

```
function rowno(rowindex) {
  var i, CellValue, Row, td;
  i = parseInt(rowindex) + 1;

  var table = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');

  Row = table.rows[i];
  td = Row.cells[1];

  CellValue = td.children[0].attributes[0].value;
  console.log(CellValue);
  window.alert(CellValue);
  return false;
}
```

here I'm calling the rowno function
`s` is the rowindex

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"Server Time", "javascript:rowno('"+s+"');", true);
```

and I'm getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null at rowno

any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do with`rowno`?

Comment: Well, it looks like `table` comes back as `null` from `getElementById`.  Can you check out the HTML in your browser to see what the page generated by ASP looks like?  Maybe it is not laid out how you assume it would be.

Comment: @WaelAbbas I want to take the rows one by one and create user authentication in firebase and add some info into firebase database

Comment: @JamesFaix https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NKYZ.jpg this is my page please check it

Comment: Why don't you try to do that from c# code?

Comment: @WaelAbbas  https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdQ8R.png this is how it looks in the browser

Comment: Where do you call the `rowno` function?

Comment: @WaelAbbas I tried to create account but i couldn't do it if you have c# code to create authentication will be better

Comment: @KirkLarkin in c# code using  this { ` Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
    "Server Time", "javascript:rowno('"+s+"');", true);`}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get null error because JS code is executed before the DOM is load, You need to call your JS code after your HTML is loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
   // add your code hear of call the function
   rowno(1);
});
```

or from your c# code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Server Time", "javascript:document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {rowno('1');});", true);
```

> The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when the initial HTML document has
>   been completely loaded and parsed

Comment: I'm calling the function in c# file with click event after load all data in the gridview

Comment: Thanks it works but i have change something but it worked but how to make loop to show all this in console?

Comment: loop throw all table rows `for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) { Row = table.rows[i]; td = Row.cells[0]; CellValue = td.children[0].attributes[0].value; console.log(CellValue); }` but I think you will not need to pass rowindex any more.

Comment: thank you I know I'll not need to pass the index but the thing is this is my first time to use **Javascript** so I have take this function over the internet **rowindex**  was already defined there that why I didn't remove it when I was trying to fix the code , Do you know about admin firebase ?

Comment: Sorry, @Ahmed I don't have previews experience with firebase.